How to manage hotfixes across main and dev branches in Git
I have two branches: main for the old release and dev for the latest release. I need to manage hotfixes effectively across these branches. Specifically, I need to:

Merge features from dev to main after it finished.
Apply hotfixes to main without missing them in dev.

What is the best approach to ensure that hotfixes applied to main are also incorporated into dev?
Additionally, although now i have same codebase in both branches, how should I handle the situation where the dev branch is behind main due to differences in commit history from merge requests? What are the best practices for synchronizing these branches?
I expect to be able to merge hotfix to dev and main.
If there is a better approach, please suggest it.

What is the problem with applying your hotfix to both dev and main? Just do it. That is the normal thing (indeed, there's a discussion of it in the git flow doc). — If you are merging from dev to main, dev will always be "behind" main. So what? What you care about is that the content (what you call the "codebase") is the same at key points. — Having said all that, I would argue that this is not a useful architecture. Having two long-lived main branches is a pain in the butt. Just have one main branch, and use a tag when you get to a release.

In my case, I need to manage two branches: main for production (with different APIs) and dev for the latest release.
Also, given that dev will always be behind main, my challenge is handling hotfixes. If I create a hotfix branch from main, how should I merge this hotfix into dev, considering that dev is behind and may have a different commit history?

Assuming the hotfix is contained in a single commit, you should be able to cherry-pick it. There can definitely be pain points, but that's the price of this architecture.

Just in case, the hotfix should be created by branching off the earliest branch of the branches you plan to apply the fix to, i.e. in your case, 'main', not 'dev' (As @TTT points out, if this was really Gitflow, then the hotfix branch would branch off the release branch.) You would then merge the hot fix into 'dev' later.  Do not try to fix the issue in 'dev' and then try to merge that commit backward into 'main'.

From the description of your branching strategy, you aren't really using Git Flow, since it doesn't appear that you're using release branches and it's unclear how you're getting features from your dev branch into main. But since you tagged git-flow, there are same concepts from it that will help you here:

Work on dev (akin to develop in Git Flow), and get it stable enough that everything on dev can be deployed to production. In order to do this you need to stop development of new features (code freeze) at some point and just focus on bug fixes. One of the main reasons Git Flow was created is to avoid having code freezes, and this is solved by cutting a release branch from dev, and then you can have bug fixes worked on release while new development continues simultaneously on dev.
When you're ready to deploy to production, deploy the latest build from your stable branch (which is either dev if you did a code freeze, or release if you created it). Then merge that stable branch into main. (Git Flow recommends using --no-ff for this merge so the first parent of history shows you exactly what was deployed to production each time.) After merging release or dev into main, merge main back into dev.
When you have a hotfix, merge hotfix into main when it's deployed, and then merge main into release if it's pending, or dev if you don't have a pending release. Specifically to your scenario: if you only have dev and main, after merging a hotfix into main, merge main back into dev.

Takeaways:

If you are using release branches, main should never be ahead of release, except for perhaps a minute or so after merging in a hotfix before main gets merged into release.
If you are not using release branches, main should never be ahead of dev, except for perhaps a minute or so after merging in a hotfix before main gets merged into dev.

